# Extract Root Domain Using Regex For Zapier

Tags: regex, zapier

I need to extract the root domain for a step within Zapier. I'm thinking regex is the only way to go.

The incoming data could show a domain in different variations:

```
www.example.com
https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com
example.com
etc
```

I rarely come across domains like .co.uk so it might be safe to just say the last two sections (with the . separating) is what I need.

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right you want to match from

> www.example.com --> example.com
>   right?

Regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z]+.+$
```

You can try it on [regex Test](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: It doesn't work as wanted: the match includes a the dot just before the domain (```www.example.com``` leads to ```.example.com```).

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the following regex :

```
[^.\/]+\.[^.]+$
```

It will match "example.com" on any of the examples you provided.

Comment: It did validate for all my examples. One example not on my list but quite common would be:

     https:// example.com (without the space in betweenn)

For that, it matches the full domain including https://

Comment: @LloydSilver Just add the ```/``` character to beginning delimiters. I edited my answer to include that case.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).